# How to find symbolic derivative using python without sympy?

Tags: python, math

I need to make a program which will differentiate a function, but I have no idea how to do this. I've only made a part which transforms the regular expression(x ^ 2 + 2 for example ) into reverse polish notation. Can anybody help me with creating a program which will a find symbolic derivatives of expression with + * / - ^

Comment: You're on the right track. But you'll have to keep thinking about it and trying things. Come back when you have a specific question on a programming problem.

Comment: They wrote "without sympy". Sounds to me like a homework problem or something.

Comment: Expressions with with + * / - ^ are _polynomials_, maybe look for the rules on "Symbolic Differentiation of Polynomials" and post a new question if you get stuck (but have some code to show).

Comment: @Iguananaut, sorry, I misread the title. I'll remove that comment.

Comment: It's OK. It's still an overly broad question off topic for SO, unfortunately.

Comment: @Iguananaut yes, you are absolutely right, I need some help with my homework. I don't even have an idea, how to solve this problem. I expected that someone will give an advice about the algorithm of finding symbolic derivative

Comment: Do you want the derivative to be in reverse Polish notation or in "regular expression"? (It seems to me that Polish notation would make your work easier than reverse Polish does.) Could the exponent of an exponential contain the variable? Does the result need to be simplified in any way?

Comment: @RoryDaulton  I want to get derivative as a regular expression. And there will be no variables in the exponent (nothing like this 5^x) and also i don't need to simplify the result(sorry if i understood something in a wrong way, English is not my native language)

Comment: @RoryDaulton thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Use a recursive routine. If an operation is unary plus or minus, leave the plus or minus sign alone and continue with the operand. (That means, recursively call the derivative routine on the operand.) If an operation is addition or subtraction, leave the plus or minus sign alone and recursively find the derivative of each operand. If the operation is multiplication, use the product rule. If the operation is division, use the quotient rule. If the operation is exponentiation, use the generalized power rule. (Do you know that rule, for `u ^ v`? It is not given in most first-year calculus books but is easy to find using logarithmic differentiation.) (Now that you have clarified in a comment that there will be no variable in the exponent, you can use the regular power rule `(u^n)' = n * u^(n-1) * u'` where `n` is a constant.) And at the base of the recursion, the derivative of `x` is `1` and the derivative of a constant is zero.

The result of such an algorithm would be very un-simplified but it would meet your stated requirements. Since this algorithm looks at an operation then looks at the operands, having the expression in Polish notation may be simpler than reverse Polish or "regular expression." But you could still do it for the expression in those forms.

If you need more detail, show us more of your work.